# Is there a quick keyboard shortcut in QT to highlight current word?

Tags: qt, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

Currently using Qt.

I notice many others have a lightning-quick ability to highlight a word, copy and paste it.

Without using moving your hands from keyboard to mouse, is there a quick way?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean while in editor? How about Ctrl + Shift + Left/Right? Thats not really a qt but rather a OS thing though

Comment: Yes, while in editor.

This demonstrates what I'm trying to do:

* Single-click on a word/command/etc.
* Now double-click 

You'll see that it highlights the entire word from start to finish, regardless of where you clicked into the word/command/etc.

I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is nothing Qt dependent, but part of your operating system. You can just search for "highlight single word <your OS>" and you should find something. On Mac e.g. it is opt+left/right to jump from word to word, and opt+shift+left/right to select whatever you jump over

Comment: @T3H40 I believe this is the correct, you should make it an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Highlighting words is a function of your operating system, rather than a Qt thing. The exact key combination to use depends on which operating system you use; google searching `highlight single word <your OS>`should give you the desired result.

Typically it's the combination for jumping the cursor to the next word, combined with shift:

- Mac OS <kbd>⌥option</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>+<kbd>⇧shift</kbd>
- Windows / Linux Distributions <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>+<kbd>⇧shift</kbd>